# Highest-quality sampler/synthesizer in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, music, midi

If I run the command `apt-cache search synth` on Ubuntu, I get 303 results.
Searching for `midi` gives me 202 results and `sampler` 59 results.

I've been told that, in theory, a good MIDI file can sound like a live band (with the right synthesizer/sampler *ware), but what I've tried so far sounds bad.

What's the highest-quality MIDI playback software available on Ubuntu?

Comment: MIDI files only sound as good as your audio hardware . I suggest you try Ubuntu studio. It also depends on what you are doing exactly. Writing, editing, or just playing midi. Keyboard?  Drum kit? Other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend Ardour.

```
sudo apt-get install ardour4
```

Other good programs are LMMS or Rosegarden, as @spacegeek224 mentioned.

If you are looking for a good synthesizer, I would recommend ZynAddSubFX or amsynth.  Hydrogen for a drum machine.

The thing that you will definitely need for a good audio setup is JACK.

```
sudo apt-get install jackd qjackctl
```

JACK is an audio server that allows you to connect various synthesizers, DAWs, etc.  Qjackctl is a GUI for it.

Many of these are available with Ubuntu Studio or with KXStudio.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `lmms` and `rosegarden`.

```
sudo apt-get install lmms rosegarden
```